# Does dropping multiple databases delete the already existing SQL Server Agent Jobs?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2017

[SQL Server noob here]
I have an instance of SQL Server 2017 which has multiple databases in it and some SQL Server Agent Jobs. If I drop all my databases will the SQL Server Agent Jobs also be removed? The reason why I'm asking is becasue I want to recreate these databases from ground up (after deleting them) and for that I will need the Agent Jobs.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Agent jobs are stored in `msdb`; dropping a user database will have no effect on Agent (unless you're dropping `msdb` and you should never be trying to drop a system database). if you have steps that reference databases you have dropped, you will need to amend those said steps.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you very much for this excellent answer!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, since the agent jobs live in `msdb`. However, the agent jobs most likely target individual databases, which you now drop, so...

What you should do is to script out the jobs, so you later can recreate them from script.